# Solving “ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away" in cyclical programs (mysql-connector-python)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python, mysql-error-2006

I provided **solution** to similar problems with the one I met recently:

I have Telegram (messenger) bot with MySQL user DB. There is connection to it in start of code causing connection was going away later about 10 hours. Therefore bot was returning errors because couldn`t get information about user.

I use `mysql-connector-python` framework. Solution is to use **class** for DB queries. You can see it and examples of using below.

Comment: needing more infos...you would need to catch those errors, and continue with processing when the DB is back up...

Comment: It isn't question. It's my solution to this problem which i couldn't find.

Comment: ok then. glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The class**:

```
import logging

import mysql.connector

class DB():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="host",
            user="user",
            passwd="password",
            database="name"
        )
        try:
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

    def execute(self, query, data=None, ret1=False):
        try:
            if not self.conn:
                self.__init__()
            else:
                if data:
                    self.cursor.execute(query, data)
                else:
                    self.cursor.execute(query)

                if 'INSERT' in query or 'UPDATE' in query or 'DELETE' in query or 'DROP' in query:
                    self.conn.commit()

                if ret1:
                    return self.cursor.fetchone()
                else:
                    return self.cursor.fetchall()

        except:
            logging.error('end', exc_info=True)
            return 'error'
```

**Table example**:

[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2uOT.png)

**Query Structure**:

```
res = DB().execute(query, protected data) # fetchall
res = DB().execute(query, protected data, True) # fetchone
```

**Examples of using**:

```
> DB().execute("CREATE TABLE users (r_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, id INT UNIQUE, name VARCHAR(255), role INT NULL DEFAULT 3)")
> DB().execute("INSERT INTO users (id, name, role) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (65453, "Mike", 1,))
> res = DB().execute(f"SELECT * FROM users")
res = [(1, 146, "Nick", 3,), (2, 155, "John", 1,), (3, 678, "Michelle", 2,)]
> res = DB().execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = %s", ("John",), ret1=True)
res = (2, 155, "John", 1,)
```

If you have some optimisation offers, write its!